# I've got Python built using VS2008, how do I install it?

Tags: python, boost, windows-installer

I'm working with boost::python and wanted to build the whole thing to make sure I can pull it off.  However, I don't see any install script or way to build the MSI so I can install it.

Anyone know where the directions are?  Or the projects I could use to make an MSI file?

Doing this on linux seems trivial:

make install

How do I do this under windows

Comment: Why would you compile python interpreter?

What does it have to do with boost::python?

Comment: In order to run Python with external modules, you have to compile python with the same version of VStudio.  I know 2.5.x was compiled with VS2005, I can't seem to find anywhere that say VS2008 was used for 2.6.4, so I wanted to build it to end all the errors there.

What I can't seem to find is the project that will let me build and MSI to do the deployment.  I'd like to do this, because we will probably end up deploying this on several machines, and the MSI file would be useful for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the python mailing list was some help.

Turns out there is an tools/msi directory and in there is python code to help build the MSI from the tree you built.  Only problem is you can't use it without having python and PythonWin installed.  So I grabbed 2.6.4 python and pythonwin and installed them.

It uses COM objects and the CabSDK from MS to build the MSI file.  And then it has a couple of "Issues" that I had to resolve.  First you need a VS2008 shell so you can

```
nmake -f msisupport.mak
```

then you need to grab a copy of [TIX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tix/files/)  (I didn't have to build it, just have it in place fore the license.terms file (probably could have just removed that list member for the same effect, but I was worried about something else being needed down below)

`("Tcl", "tcl8*", "license.terms"),
        ("Tk", "tk8*", "license.terms"),
        ("Tix", "Tix-*", "license.terms")):`

had to be changed to:

`("Tcl", "tcl-8*", "license.terms"),
        ("Tk", "tk-8*", "license.terms"),
        ("Tix", "Tix*", "license.terms")):`

because the package names have evidently changed in the not to distant past?

After that, I ran `c:\python26\python msi.py` and then it griped about the python264.chm being missing, so instead of trying to build it, I grabbed the one from the copy of python I had to install in order to build python and dumped it in the expected location.

Oh yea, I also had to go to the PC directory and

```
nmake -f icons.mak
```

This gave me a runnable msi file to install python (which was already installed, so that I could build the msi file to install my own version).  Oh well, at least it is built now.  Whew!

Answer (score 0):

All of this is much easier with [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), plus there's the fact that it's likely to be compatible with the ABI of the official package so that you can just install that instead and only build extensions with MinGW.

Comment: The official package was built with VS2005, and somehow, someone builds an MSI file from a completed build......